# How to quickly write large amounts of data into txt files

Tags: c++, performance, stream, streamwriter

Recently I was trying to write pointcloud data to .txt file by using C++ in Visual Studio 2010. At the beginning I used ostream to output the data, but I found it slow when writing the data.

My code :

```
std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(filename.c_str());
for(int index = 0;index < pointcloud.size();index++){
  outfile<<pointcloud[index].x<<pointcloud[index].y<<pointcloud[index].z
  <<pointcloud[index].r<<pointcloud[index].g<<pointcloud[index].b<<'\n';
}
outfile<<std::endl;
```

The output pointcloud is very huge, almost 0.5G. It takes minutes to write into .txt file. How can I improve the speed of writing down the data? I thought it might be the problem of the size of cache buffer, but not sure. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You could use std::copy to improve the performance.

Comment: Is the source data (`pointcloud`) all in-memory, or is it a container wrapper to "cloud-based" data?  If it's the latter, your issue may be there???

Comment: Get a faster hard drive, and more RAM. Your performance is limited by your hard drive's speed. Short of changing the laws of physics of this universe, the only answer is faster hardware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IOStream to perform better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better)

Comment: You could write chuncks of a size well suited to the drive/os's buffer size, but the stream is probably already doing that for you. Have you researched whether the write speed is appropriate for the amount of data? Just because it's slow doesn't mean there's a problem with the write.

Comment: Here are some benchmarks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308793/explanation-information-sought-windows-write-i-o-performance-with-fsync-flus/18434227#18434227

Comment: I have found a way to solve this problem myself.The performance bottlenecks is not caused by IO.If I use outfile<<(std::string)str.c_str(); （str is a Long string like 200MB），This may take less than one second.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have found a way to solve this problem myself.The performance bottlenecks is
```

not caused by IO.If I use outfile<<(std::string)str.c_str(); （str is a Long string 
like 200MB），This may take less than one second.so I use multithread to splice the 
data into a long string and output through IO stream.The speed is increased by 
about 6 times on a 4core computer.